# Laravel/homestead - restore mysql databases

Tags: mysql, vagrant, homestead

I lost all my databases on vagrant while I was reinstalling boxes. How can I restore them from TimeMachine?

Comment: You need to import databases again otherwise if you have backups then you can restore those.